# which of the OR statement was selected?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How do I know which of the OR statement was selected?
I would like the fetch to show the colour.col which was selected.

```
$parsed = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *
FROM colour
LEFT JOIN shape ON colour.id = shape.id
WHERE shape.col1 = 'square' AND  colour.col1 = 'blue'
OR shape.col1 = 'square' AND  colour.col2 = 'pink'
OR shape.col1 = 'circle' AND  colour.col3 = 'red'
OR shape.col1 = 'triangle' AND  colour.col4 = 'yellow'
OR shape.col1 = 'rectangle' AND  colour.col5 = 'green'
");



while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row[col1] . "</td>";

**which colour column was selected?**
I would like to see the column header here (colour.col1,colour.col2...) not the value    (pink,green...)

echo "</tr>";

}
```

Comment: Why storing the colour in 5 different fields? BTW `$row['col1']` will work better than `$row[col1]`

Comment: for $row[col1] php will first look for constant named "col" in symbol table,better use $row['col']

Comment: My actual tables are different, I have just simplified it here. The colour columns in the actual table have unique info. Thanks will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use an extra column to indicate the selected color:

```
SELECT *, 
       case when shape.col1 = 'square' and colour.col1 = 'blue'
            then 'blue' 
            when shape.col1 = 'square' and colour.col2 = 'pink'
            then 'pink' 
            ...
       end as selected_color
FROM colour
where ...
```

Comment: This my working code     $result = mysql_query("SELECT *,
    case when shape.col1 = 'square' and colour.col1 = 'blue'
    then 'blue' 
    when shape.col1 = 'square' and colour.col2 = 'pink'
    then 'pink' 
    end as selected_color
    FROM colour
    LEFT JOIN shape ON colour.id = shape.id
    WHERE shape.col1 = 'square' AND  colour.col1 = 'blue'
    OR shape.col1 = 'square' AND  colour.col2 = 'pink'
    OR shape.col1 = 'circle' AND  colour.col3 = 'red'
    OR shape.col1 = 'triangle' AND  colour.col4 = 'yellow'
    OR shape.col1 = 'rectangle' AND  colour.col5 = 'green'
    ");

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM colour LEFT JOIN shape ON colour.id = shape.id
WHERE (shape.col1 = 'square' AND  colour.col1 = 'blue') 
OR (shape.col1 = 'square' AND  colour.col2 = 'pink') 
OR (shape.col1 = 'circle' AND  colour.col3 = 'red') 
OR (shape.col1 = 'triangle' AND  colour.col4 = 'yellow') 
OR (shape.col1 = 'rectangle' AND  colour.col5 = 'green')
");
```

i think should be like this one...maybe you can try it in sql^^

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help you! Use **mysql_fetch_row**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,email FROM people WHERE id = '42'");
if (!$result) {
    echo 'err: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo $row[0]; // 42
echo $row[1]; // email
```

Comment: I would like to see the column header here (colour.col1,colour.col2...) not the value    (pink,green...)

Answer (score -2):

Format your Query Properly like below and you'll get to know.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *
FROM colour
LEFT JOIN shape ON colour.id = shape.id
WHERE (shape.col1 = 'square' AND  colour.col1 = 'blue')
OR (shape.col1 = 'square' AND  colour.col2 = 'pink')
OR (shape.col1 = 'circle' AND  colour.col3 = 'red')
OR (shape.col1 = 'triangle' AND  colour.col4 = 'yellow')
OR (shape.col1 = 'rectangle' AND  colour.col5 = 'green')
");
```

Comment: thats not nessesery, the Boolean algebra works that way anyway

Comment: YEs But as question asked "How do I know which of the OR statement was selected?" ... query doesn't make any sense with bunch or AND & OR all together...

Comment: Both formats gives me the same result. See my edit    **which colour column was selected?**
I would like to see the column header here (colour.col1,colour.col2...) not the value    (pink,green...)